# Intel HAXM Error when Installing on Windows 10 Home (No Hyper-V)

Tags: android, windows, emulation, haxm

all!

Today was my first time installing Android Studio on my Windows 10 Home Edition laptop and things became complex *quickly*.  Android Studio seemingly installed, but Intel HAXM didn't.  (Error message is below.)  Further Googling showed me that Hyper-V wasn't available on Windows 10 Home Edition and was seemingly forcibly removed/super disabled on a recent service pack release.

How important is HAXM for Android development since I lack an Android phone?  If I don't use Android Studio, what Android emulator and version should I use?

Thankee!

[image: Intel HAXM Error Message]

Comment: Check your windows Hyper-V is disabled on windows features. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v#enable-the-hyper-v-role-through-settings

Answer (score 1):

HAXM is a cross-platform hardware-assisted virtualization engine (hypervisor), widely used as an accelerator for Android Emulator and QEMU. It has always supported running on Windows and macOS and has been ported to other host operating systems as well, such as Linux and NetBSD

It is Intel's virtualization extension for Android Emulator on x86.

You can use an emulator with the ARM image instead of HAXM provided that you installed it in your SDK manager.

Check your SDK manager and install the ARM image for the API level you want, then go to the AVD manager and make a virtual device using ARM as the CPU.

Note: ARM images are not available in the latest API levels, but it is available on API level 25 below

Comment: I also downloaded and installed Genymotion.  What else should I download and install?

Thankee!

Comment: @GregCampbell I didn't ask you to download Genymotion. read my answer again

Answer (score -2):

I think you don't need it for work with Android Studio.
If you don't have an Android Phone, you will need to set up Genymotion.